# Comparing two MySQL dattetime columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have a payments table with the following two columns in it:

```
created_at
paid_at
```

What I would like to do, is select all rows where:

```
paid_at >= (created_at + 30 days)
```

So, while I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at >= paid_at;
```

What's the syntax for:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at >= (paid_at + 30 days);
```

This is a Rails application, and I usually do this via ActiveRecord queries, but it seems as if this is not something ActiveRecord is built for, so I need to use a native query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`date_add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(paid_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(paid_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

See [MySQL 8.0 - 12.6 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mysql function date_add

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(paid_at , INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= paid_at + INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

You may use also

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(paid_at, created_at) <= 30;
```